# Android Studio - Why is this function not called?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning Android Studio & Kotlin and came across a interesting error.
[image]

Notice how the squeezeState() is in red, or says that the function doesn't exist even though its at the bottom and has been declared properly.
Why doesn't Kotlin pickup the function reference?

Comment: You're defining `squeezeState` inside of a function, aren't you? If that is how you want to do it, then you must define it before you call it, i.e. before the `when` part.

Comment: Oh so it should be on the top?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the screenshot, but I'd say yes put it at the top

Comment: @javadssmh You do you, I prefer defining functions inside another function.

Comment: @javadssmh Can you read the title and tell me what language I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise that this isn't JavaScript and that you need to declare the function before calling it

Comment: Even in Javascript, function hoisting is largely considered an awkward misfeature. Most style guides will recommend using `let myfunc = function() { ... }` syntax just to *avoid* that behavior.

Comment: If the function is defined in the top level (e.g. in the class) you can declare it below another function that calls it. If you're declaring a function *inside* another function it needs to happen before you try to access it, same as a variable

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank you for the helpful insight. JavaScript is a weird language at times

Comment: @cactustictacs That's very helpful to know, thank you!